# React Native Unhandled promise rejection: FirebaseError: Expected type 'Ia', but it was: a custom xl object

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update some data in a document in my "chatRooms" collection in firebase. I am using React Native and I am getting this error. Can someone tell me what these types mean as I have literally no idea what Ia or a custom xl object is.

Code :

```
    async function sendMessage()
    {
        console.log(message);
        console.log(props.chatKey);
        const mydoc = doc(db, "chatRooms" , props.chatKey);
        const docRef = await getDoc(mydoc);
        const time = Date.now();
        const newMessage = {time : time , message : message};
        var allMessages = docRef.get("messages");
        allMessages.push(newMessage);
        const members = docRef.get("members");
        console.log(members);
        const newData = {members : members , messages : allMessages};
        await setDoc(docRef, newData);
        console.log("Message Sent");


    }
```

The error :

[image]